# I am not able to go to the graphical mode in linux redhat 7

Tags: command-line, redhat-enterprise-linux, gui

I am not able access the graphical mode directly in redhat 7 as every time is as i every time it boot directly into terminal and for GUI mode,  had to start it with `startx` command. so could you help me in this matter ,

I mean how to resolve this problem???

thanking you

Comment: Which desktop do you use?

Comment: dell precision t7610

Comment: I meant which Desktop, like Gnome, KDE, XFCE,...

Comment: Desktop environment in redhat 7  is  Gnome 3